# How to compile a py file from another py file by using a module ? (Therefore not Cmd)

Tags: python, compilation, executable

I want to make a code (that I'll call **compiler.py**), that'll compile any py file I need without using cmd commands, only modules(Things that are compilable So I can still Use my compiler on other
devices).

Here are some examples of code to illustrate what I am asking for:
Here is how compiler.py would look like :
[compiler.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAhJ7.png)

And this is randomprogramm.py :
[randomprogramm.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPLQR.png)

Any Idea on how to proceed ?

Comment: Python compiler package was discontinued after Python 2.6. You can try that, but you'll have to use older version of python. https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/library/compiler.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.